# How can I compare a set of numbers to find out which one is closer to the generated one?

Tags: javascript

I am making a game where two players enter a number and then the computer randomly generates a number between 1 and 10.

example:

```
var number1 = prompt("player1 enter number here");
var number2 = prompt("player2 enter number here");
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
```

I can't figure out how I am going to compare both numbers to the generated one and have the computer decide which player has the closer number.

Comment: compare `(randomNumber ~number1)` and `(randomNumber ~number2).` which is bigger is not close to `randomNumber `.. simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems quite simple... just check if negative differences

**EDIT**: as suggested, is more polite using `Math.abs()`:

```
var dif1 = Math.abs(number1 - randomNumber);
var dif2 = Math.abs(number2 - randomNumber);
if (dif1 < dif2) 
    // first value is closer
```

Comment: You can use `Math.abs`.